# JSON data word Max interfering with PHP

Tags: php, json, max

I am using php to decode this json data https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/play.mineverge.net all my code works fine and I get all the JSON data fine although when I try to get players: max: it will not load the page.

Working JSON code to get online players:

```
$playersonline->players->online;
```

Not working code because MAX interfers with PHP

```
$playersonline->players->max;
```

So in short max interferes with PHP so what do I do?

Comment: Don't convert the JSON into PHP objects. Use the decode option to convert to an array.

Comment: @cgTag Is there a reason to avoid decoding to objects?

Comment: @Nima there is no major reason for either. You would use objects when you knew the data structure was what you wanted, and objects can have methods attached to them at run-time. So you could add a "save()" function as an example, but generally I would always go with arrays.

Comment: @Nydigov I don't understand the part that you say `Max Interfers with PHP`. Would you please explain that? And as a side note, I could echo `$playersonline->players->max;` as well as `$playersonline->players->online;` without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON into arrays by passing `true` as the second argument in `json_decode`.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/play.mineverge.net");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['players']['max'];
```

Comment: This answer should just be deleted. There is no need for the true parameter on json_decode as without it `$data->players->max` is accessible without error. @Nydigov is obviously doing something else wrong, but since there was no real code provided, there really can be no real answer.

Comment: @BrianGottier that's fair but deleting answers is not how we moderate answers. Your comment would be lost and then nothing of value is added to the community. Allowing people to see my mistake helps other people. Sometimes wrong answers reflect common thinking and helps direct people in the right direction.